# How do you specify the port number in a oledb connection string to SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

Just found this out, so i am answering my own question :)

Use a comma where you would normally use a colon. This can be a problem for named instances, as you seem to need to specify the port even if it is the default port 1433.

Example:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=192.168.200.123,1433; Initial Catalog=Northwind; User Id=WebUser; Password=windy"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/. It is a brilliant resource for connection strings.

Comment: That's the website I use when I need to check specific settings in a connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Good call BlackWasp, actually that is where i found the answer! (But it was somewhat buried, so i wrote this one which is hopefully clearer)

Comment: I have to admit that I opened the SQL 2K5 page and it wasn't obvious without searching the page!